# How to resolve the path of a file name in python with symlink on linux

Tags: python-3.x

i am trying to resolve the path of a file that has been symlink in python on linux os
 i have tried this

```
# sets up the log directory for all files
log_dir = os.path.join(os.path.normpath(os.getcwd() + os.sep + os.pardir),'logs')
```

Answer (score 1):

try [os.readlink](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.readlink). Assuming `log_dir` is your soft link,

```py
soft_link = os.path.join(
    os.path.normpath(os.getcwd() + os.sep + os.pardir),
    'logs',
)
abs_path = os.readlink(soft_link)
```

**os.readlink**

> Return a string representing the path to which the symbolic link points.